# Delay between celery tasks scheduled by airflow

Tags: celery, airflow

I was trying to run the following simple workflow by using celeryExecutor in Airflow:

```
default_args = {
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime.now(),
}

dag = DAG('HelloWorld', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None)
default_args=default_args)

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='task_1',
    bash_command='echo "Hello World from Task 1"; sleep 0.1',
    dag=dag)
t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='task_2',
    bash_command='echo "Hello World from Task 2"; sleep 0.2',
    dag=dag)
t2.set_upstream(t1)
```

However, it always has ~5 seconds delay between task_1 and task_2. Following are the airflow.cfg snapshot:

```
[scheduler]
# Task instances listen for external kill signal (when you clear tasks
# from the CLI or the UI), this defines the frequency at which they should
# listen (in seconds).
job_heartbeat_sec = 0.1

# The scheduler constantly tries to trigger new tasks (look at the
# scheduler section in the docs for more information). This defines
# how often the scheduler should run (in seconds).
scheduler_heartbeat_sec = 1
```

It looks like that celery is one that causes the delay, but, if true, how to set the celery worker heartbeat interval (or pooling rate) from airflow config or API?

Comment: could be some issue with that 'start_date' set to just datetime.now()  see "Using a start_date of datetime.now() can lead to unpredictable behavior, and your DAG never starting. It's recommended to subtract a timespan to force the scheduler to recognize the start_date. ***"

Comment: Can you be more specific what `start_date` should be? Please note that my `schedule_interval` has been set to be `None`

Comment: Sorry I misread the info, looks like this is expected, please see here - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/airbnb_airflow/dNskpaOYNQo

Answer (score 5):

As a batch scheduler Airflow doesn't currently guarantee super low latency. The aim for the project has been to make it possible to do sub-minute latency at scale, but it's common for this go up to a few minutes in larger environments.

If latency is around 1 minutes, it doesn't make sense to do a chain of 1-2 seconds tasks. Typically the duration of an Airflow task should be counted in minutes, not seconds (there are exceptions though). Airflow is not Amazon Lambda.

It's probably possible to fine-tune and get to say <= 5 seconds, but that will become impossible to provide these guarantees as you scale the system.